# JavaScript Array.prototype.reduce -- destructuring properties that might not exist

Tags: javascript

Given the following data structure, where product_variations can have other product_variations as children, I am looking for a terse algorithm that will extract all of the 'product_variations' that are children to one 'product_variation', but all I have is the SKU

```
  product_variations: [
        {   
            product_variation_id: "", 
            variation_name: variation_name, 
            variation_item_name: "test",
            sku: "SKU000",
            price: price,
            stock: stock,
            topLevel: true,
            child_variations: [{sku: "SKU001"}]
        },  
    ]
```

I was thinking reduce could be useful for this, as I can iterate through each of the child_variations, and then use a find function to grab the relevant SKU from the product_variations array and push that to the accumulator. I am trying to get something like this to work:

```
const extractChildrenVariations = (variationItem, variations) => {
    return variationItem.child_variations.reduce( (arr, {sku: s}) => arr.push(
        variations.find( v => v.sku == s)
    ), []) 
}
```

I think this could be the problem; sometimes there aren't any child_variations to begin with, ie. `child_variations: [{}]`

Anyone see what I might be doing wrong? I am confident that if the SKU is in the child_variations array that variations.find with that SKU will turn something up (since it definitely exists)

Comment: Why is there an empty object in the array when there are no child_variations? The array should be empty instead (`[]` instead of `[{}]`).

Comment: If it was called on an empty array, would it just return the base accumulator?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ah ok cool thanks, I'll have to change the API but that was annoying me anyway. Edit: @Paulpro that fixed it for me, if you wanna post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be more readable with `array.filter`:

```js
const extractChildrenVariations = (variationItem, variations) => {
    return variations.filter(v => variationItem.child_variations.find(cv => cv.sku === v.sku));
}
```

Comment: The problem is, child_variations doesn't hold the actual variations, just a reference

Comment: @DanielThompson Ahhh, I understand

Comment: Ahh ok yeah that does make more sense